# how to add rewrite rule to wordpress default post type

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules, query-variable

hello trying to add rewrite rule to default post type with this

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_rewrite');
function add_my_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('(.*)/server/([^/]+)','index.php?p=$matches[1]&server=$matches[2]','top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);
}
function add_query_vars_filter($vars){
  $vars[] = "server";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars','add_query_vars_filter');
```

but doesn't work
let's say my post url is `http://localhost/wordpress/movie-slug/`
i want the url to be like that `http://localhost/wordpress/movie-slug/server/1` with adding the parameter server to the url
how can i do that
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p` query var expects a post ID, use `name` instead. Also note that rules should only be flushed when they change, as it's a computationally expensive operation. It's best to do that on theme change or plugin activation, whichever is appropriate for where your code is located. You can also do this by just visiting the Settings > Permalinks page in admin.

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_rewrite');
function add_my_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(.*)/server/([^/]+)',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]&server=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
function add_query_vars_filter($vars){
    $vars[] = "server";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars','add_query_vars_filter');
```